# Using variables from parent in nested postgresql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm have a pretty long SQL routine that gets a few parameters and runs through a whole bunch of `CASE` statements. I have the following structure:

```
DO $$
DECLARE var INTEGER = "someColumn" FROM TABLE LIMIT 1;

BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.fn(var2 boolean) returns decimal AS 
$fn$ SELECT CASE WHEN var2 THEN var::decimal ELSE 0::decimal END $fn$ language sql;
$$
```

And using `var` inside of `fn` does not seem to quite work. As in the `column does not exist`. Is there a way to make it work, am I maybe thinking too complicated?

Edit: fixed the type that was missing. In the original code there is a type declaration, the declaration is not the problem. Using the variable in the nested function is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. **THIS IS NOT THE BEST PRACTICE**. It can be done, but it is not recommended to use nested functions.

The problem is that `var` is in a different scope than the function. You have to "write" the function as an independent unit. You can do this with `EXECUTE` and `FORMAT`.

Here is an example of a function that shows `var` as a message:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    sql text; -- To "write" the function
    var integer := id FROM table_name ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
BEGIN
-- To make it hapend I use $test$ to set the function.
-- FORMAT is to allocate var into the function through '%s'.
-- you have to use the correct sintax acording to the data type.
    sql :=  FORMAT($test$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS $FUNCTION$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%s';
END; $FUNCTION$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
$test$,var);
    EXECUTE sql;
END; $$
```

Comment: That was an error of mine. My actual declaration contains a type (I can't post the original code here) but when trying to `CREATE` the `FUNCTION`, the column `var` in my example does not exist. The variable works elsewhere in the script, it's just in that function that it's unknown.

Comment: Is the `CREATE FUNCTION` inside an `EXECUTE`?

Comment: Nope, no `EXECUTE` in my code. Edit: everything else is pure SQL, using the declared variables at the top (there are 8 of them).

Comment: @david1602 Changed my answer, i think is what you need.

Comment: I see, thank you for the efforts! It seems waaay too complicated. I know SQL isn't an actual "programming language", but I thought the stuff with the different scopes might work, similar to it working in JavaScript. Anyway, I think I'm going to opt for just selecting it in a different CTE  and joining it, rather than trying to obtain the number via a function.

Edit: I sadly cannot vote because I have less than 15 reputation, but I marked it as accepted solution at least!